# Recording sql statements performing on a table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is there a way to record sql statements performing on table in Oracle? I need to record those queries for a table in production and hopefully rerun them in my test to make sure I don't mess up table modification.

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 4):

Oracle Database Replay is exactly the feature you are looking for: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-replay-099279.html

Comment: can I filter the statements for just one table?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle automatically records any SQL executed against the instance in a table called **v$sqlarea**